# Error DBF file reader in C#

Tags: c#, dbf

ERROR: Syntax error in query.  Incomplete query clause.
Please help me.

```
        string db_file = null;
        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath + "\\out";
        op.Filter = "DBF file|*.dbf"; 
        if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            db_file = op.FileName;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(op.FileName);

                   String ConnectionString;
                   ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fi.DirectoryName + ";Extended Properties=dBase 5.0;Mode=Read|Write|Share Deny None;Persist Security Info=True";
          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection dBaseConnection;
          dBaseConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
          dBaseConnection.Open();
          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand dBaseCommand;

              dBaseCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * From '" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name) + "'", dBaseConnection);
          System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader dBaseDataReader;
          dBaseDataReader = dBaseCommand.ExecuteReader();
          while (dBaseDataReader.Read()) 
          {
              MessageBox.Show("x");
          }
          dBaseDataReader.Close();
```

ERROR: Syntax error in query.  Incomplete query clause.

Comment: don't remove the extension while reading the file with select query.

Comment: Should those quotes be in there? around Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [VfpOleDb provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839).  Here is the connection string using that provider:

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=VfpOleDb;Data Source=" + fi.DirectoryName;
```

Comment: @AzikАббасOFF, since this worked, be sure to give credit by clicking the checkmark next to this answer so others are not thinking its still an open question needing an answer for support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
("Select * From " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name) , dBaseConnection)
```

without the quotes 'Path..'.

Hope it helps.